# Responsive Tables and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, responsive

First of all I must say that I am a complete rookie at web development(2 months working on). So forgive me about any "stupid" comments or questions.

I have a table which holds date stored in MySQL database. I use a form to send these data to the table.

My question is:

"Can I create a hyperlink on each ID of the table so when I click on it, it will display the data of the record BUT on the same page?"

All I could do was to display the table in another page.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to SO! What language are you using right now? PHP?

Comment: Yeahp. I am using PHP

Answer (score 1):

First when someone read "responsive table" normally we think on [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design), maybe the correct title would be data managament from tables.

To answer your question, I would say yes, you can create a hyperlink on each ID display the data, this hyperlink would make another query on the database, the way you want to do i would use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) that's really complicated at start, so I recommend you to search some tutorials.